# Update Label by using pickerview and text field

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, swift2, xcode7

I have a PickerView that deposit values. This values will be calculate with a user textfield input. The result will show in a label. That works for me.
By starting the app the textfield have a fix number of 1. 
How can I now update my label automatically by use the Pickerview? 
I read and try many things but it don´t works.
Maybe it is a little thing, but i don´t see it.

```
import UIKit

class BalkenbewehrungVC: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // Deklarationen Pickerview
    var multiplicator : Double = 0.0

    let multiplicators = [0.0,6.0,8.0,10.0,12.0,14.0,16.0,20.0,25.0,26.0,28.0,30.0,32.0,36.0,40.0,50.0]

    let PI = 3.1415

    // Pickerview füllen
    var pickerDataSource = ["---","Ø 6","Ø 8","Ø 10","Ø 12","Ø 14","Ø 16","Ø 20","Ø 25","Ø 26","Ø 28","Ø 30","Ø 32","Ø 36","Ø 40","Ø 50"]


    // Picker im aktivieren
    @IBOutlet weak var Pickerview: UIPickerView!


    // Ausgabewert As = xxxx cm
    @IBOutlet var AusgabePicker: UILabel!

    // Eingabe Anzahl Stäbe
    @IBOutlet var AnzahlStab: UITextField!

      @IBAction func test(sender: UITextField) {

        if AnzahlStab.text!.isEmpty {

            AnzahlStab.text = "1"

            let result1 = (multiplicator / 10) * (multiplicator / 10) * PI / 4 * 1

            AusgabePicker.text! = String(format:"%.3f", result1)


        } else {

            let result = (multiplicator / 10) * (multiplicator / 10) * PI / 4 * (AnzahlStab.text! as NSString).doubleValue
            // let resultString = "\(result)"


            AusgabePicker.text = String(format:"%.3f", result)
        }

    }

// Picker - feste Reihen
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Picker - Aufaddierung neuer Reihen
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerDataSource.count

    }

    // Picker - Datenübernahme multiplicator in Picker
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerDataSource[row]


    }

    // Picker - Wertefestlegung Picker
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        multiplicator = multiplicators[row]
        _ = NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: multiplicator), numberStyle:.DecimalStyle)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `didSelectRow` method for the `pickerView`, set the label's text to your newly calculated value.

**Update**: To update the label's text depending on the textField's input, inside your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, add this line

```
AnzahlStab.delegate = self
```

and then add the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method, and inside it update the label's text to the new value. This method is called when you are done with editing the text field.

Comment: Pickerview update label now! But now textfield input not update label directlly. Only after spinning pickerview. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Where i must add the textFieldDidEndEditing method

Comment: Yeah.Nice. Have it :o). Thanks very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

Need to call function test in picker view `didSelectRow`. Or Simply Replace your `didSelectRow` with following code.

> ```
> func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
>         multiplicator = multiplicators[row]
>         _ = NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: multiplicator), numberStyle:.DecimalStyle)
>         self.test(AnzahlStab)
>     }
> ```

Hope this Answer will help you.